# When does my truce end?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

I recently won a war against my neighbor but he has some more counties that obviously should be in my realm, and not his. Where can I see when our truce ends and I can declare war on him again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Truce information is available in the Diplomacy section of your character sheet.

[image: Portion of Character sheet with Diplomacy section indicated.]

While alliances and wars will display on both parties character sheets, Truce information is only displayed and binding for the war's aggressor.

Comment: I have seen this occasionally go missing in my games. If it does, I recommend a reload!

Comment: Collary of the last paragraph is that you always should look at your own character sheet. And yes, if you are a warmonger, it will be filled with truces :). It doesn't matter whether your target's character sheet says he has a truce with you or not.

Comment: And remember that truces are between people, not realms -- so if the king you signed the peace treaty with were to trip and fall onto a poisonous spider...